# How to get request page parameter from reportextension in Al Business central

Tags: report, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I have a variable in the base report which i can't access in the reportextension as it is not declared protected, but it is used in the requestpage of the base report.

Is there a way to somehow get the value of NoOfCopies?

var NoOfCopies: Integer;

I failed to implement
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-get-report-parameters-with-virtual-tables